# Initial passwords pre-expiration in Red Hat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, password-management

I need inital passwords which was set by root to be pre-expired. For example:

```
root# useradd user1
root# passwd user1
```

After that password need to be expired. It can be achieved by command

```
root# chage -d 0 user1
```

But I need this to be done automatically whenever root set password for another user.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, password aging can only be configured with chage or useradd commands. Setting the aging via passwd command is not possible.